# Select на Iphone

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, frontend

Здравствуйте, стилизовал селект в мобильной версии сайта с помощью плагина, на android все работает отлично, а в iOS при нажатии на селект появляется стандартное меню выбора вариантов. Как сделать чтобы это меню не появлялось а появлялись стилизованные option?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант, можно сделать это сторонними jquery плагинами. Например, этим http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/demo.html

Comment: он уже стилизован jQuery Form Styler

Comment: Любой select на который тапаешь работает так. Очевидно, сделайте не на селекте, а, например, на диве конструкцию свою.

Для отдельного разговора, почему неназванная вами библиотека не делает этого на айфонах, но умеет на андроиде.

Comment: @АнтонЛепетков я не про внешний вид говорю. Есть плагины, которые берут `select` и заменяют его на `ul, li` или `div`. Вот я о них говорю.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо всем.

Comment: Ничего делать не надо! Оставьте как есть. Нет ничего лучше стандартного меню селекта на телефоне, к которому все привыкли.

Comment: Сам я это прекрасно понимаю, но заказчики требуют.

Comment: @Yarikhp не поделишься решением? ))

Answer (score 1):

Надо убрать строку:

```
if (iOS) return;
```

Автор плагина решил просто не выводить выпадающий список для iOS-устройств, т.к. на момент разработки плагина в iOS, видимо, была проблема со скрытием нативного списка.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]